# Optimal way to run as many VMs as possible

Tags: virtual-machine

My objective is to open as many VMs as possible on my desktop with i6700k and 16Gb RAM.

They all run the same program in XP. So my question is if I should allocate all 4cores and 16 Gb RAM to each VMs or I should allocate only 1CPU  and 16 RAM DIVIDED equally to them? Currently, I have adopted the later and found the CPU is the bottle neck from the task manager.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible for you to allocate 16 GB to a single VM because your host Os wouldn't have any and it certainly not possible to run multiple VMs that have 16 GB either

Comment: @Ramhound depending on the virtualization solution you might overbook it but you're right that you will run into issues if you exhaust the physical memory.

Comment: What virtualization solution you're using? [XP System requirements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/314865/system-requirements-for-windows-xp-operating-systems) would suggest that each VM should have about 128 MB RAM. The safest solution would be to reserve some of the RAM for your host (probably taken care of by the virtualization solution) and give each VM a fixed amount.

Comment: Okay, I realized that i need to save some RAM for the host. Provided that I did so, what would be the best way to open as many VMs as possible?

Comment: @Seth - How a Hypervisor Type 2 (any hypervisor that runs within another os would be considered this) works is pretty constant.  Is your comment based on that reality? Windows XP a 32-bit operating system could only use 4 GB.

Comment: @Ramhound From what I can see he hasn't actually mentioned whenever he's exploring options or what virtualization solution he's using. He just mentioned his hardware. You're correct that for desktop virtualization you wouldn't be able to overbook. If you use something like ESXi or similar you might be able to. That's all I wanted to point out. The XP bis is about him running XP VMs and the Microsoft recommendations which are linked.

Comment: What he described is a hypervisor type 2 ("on my desktop")

Comment: I am using VMware workstation. Not sure if this is the virtualization solution you mentioned.